# @Sql(config = @SqlConfig(encoding = "UTF-8")) globally set

Tags: java, spring, testing

I have a lots of DAO tests in persistance layer. I use Spring with H2 and EasyMock.

I have lots of tests with custom script annotated like this:

```
@Test
@Sql(config = @SqlConfig(encoding = "UTF-8"), scripts = "dataSetWithChangesetsOnly.sql")
public void testCreate_Ok() {
// ...
```

It's a lot of boilerplate code in annotations. If I set encoding at the top of the test class, it does not work for those custom annotated test methods.

What I need to do is set encoding globally. Ideally for the whole maven module.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

try to add the following code in build.gradle.

```
tasks.withType(Test) {
    systemProperty "file.encoding", "UTF-8"
}
```